# How to show info in second gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I use the Nordwind DB

This is how my app looks:

[image: App]

I want to select a row from the first grid view and show the orders from those Customers in the second gridview also I would like to filter 1 or more columns in the first gridview.

GridView1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True");conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", conn);

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.CustomerID = (string)rdr["CustomerID"];
        c.CompanyName = (string)rdr["CompanyName"];
        c.ContactName = (string)rdr["ContactName"];
        c.City = (string)rdr["City"];
        c.Country = (string)rdr["Country"];
        c.Phone = (string)rdr["Phone"];
        Customers.Add(c);
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = Customers;
}
```

GridView2:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True"); 
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Orders", conn);

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<Order> Orders = new List<Order>();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Order o = new Order();
        o.OrderID = (int)rdr["OrderID"];
        o.OrderDate = (DateTime)rdr["OrderDate"];
        o.ShipName = (string)rdr["ShipName"];
        o.ShipCity = (string)rdr["ShipCity"];
        o.ShipCountry = (string)rdr["ShipCountry"];
        Orders.Add(o);
    }

    dataGridView2.DataSource = Orders;
}
```

Select the whole row:

```
        {
            Customer c = (Customer)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        }
```

I think the SqlCommand is not good in GridView2 also I think I need to update the form but I have no idea how to do that.

Could someone give me the right code and maybe even an explanation for what part does what?

Thanks in advance if you need more info please say it.

Comment: You need to get the value of the customer (of the selected row) and pass that to the sql for the second gridview...

Comment: And how to do that i made this

```private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer c = (Customer)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        }```

Can I use that?

Comment: Use the debugger.  What is the value of "c" when you run this code?

Comment: Well that gives you the object..Looks like your order object needs customerId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this in the `CellContentClick` but in the `SelectionChanged` event handler. The orders must have a `CustomerID` you can use to filter in a WHERE-clause:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow?.DataBoundItem is Customer customer) {
        var orders = new List<Order>();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(STR_Connection))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Orders where CustomerID=@cid", conn)) {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cid", SqlDbType.NChar, 5).Value = customer.CustomerID;

            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (rdr.Read()) {
                    var o = new Order {
                        OrderID = (int)rdr["OrderID"],
                        CustomerID = (string)rdr["CustomerID"],
                        OrderDate = (DateTime)rdr["OrderDate"],
                        ShipName = (string)rdr["ShipName"],
                        ShipCity = (string)rdr["ShipCity"],
                        ShipCountry = (string)rdr["ShipCountry"]
                    };
                    orders.Add(o);
                }
            }
        }

        dataGridView2.DataSource = orders;
    } else {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
    }
}
```

It is important to pass parameters as command parameter and to concatenate it into a SQL command string. This can lead to a SQL injection attack (here probably not, but in the general case...). It also improves the performance of the query, as the SQL-Server can cache the execution plan, since the command string does not change for different customers.

Put the connection, the command and the reader in using-statements to have them automatically disposed.

---

Filtering by the the textbox works very much the same way. Reload the customers in the `TextChanged` or `Validated` or `Leave` event of the textbox:

```
private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadCustomers(txtFilter.Text);
}
```

and also in the Load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadCustomers();
}
```

The difference between `TextChanged` and the other two events is that the former fires for every character entered. For the others to work, you must leave the textbox.

Then you will have to handle the two cases where the filter is empty or not. If it is empty, either select the customers without WHERE-clause (i.e. return all rows) or don't return rows at all (`dataGridView1.DataSource = null;`). Otherwise set up an appropriate where clause. Maybe

```
WHERE CompanyName LIKE @filter OR ContactName LIKE @filter
```

Then embed the filter string in `%`. This is the wildcard character in SQL.

```
private void LoadCustomers(string filter = null) // Optional filter parameter
{
    string sql = "select * from Customers";
    SqlParameter filterParameter = null;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter)) {
        sql += " WHERE CompanyName LIKE @filter OR ContactName LIKE @filter";
        filterParameter = new SqlParameter("@filter", SqlDbType.NVarChar) {
            Value = "%" + filter + "%" // Add wildcards.
        };
    }

    var Customers = new List<Customer>();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(STR_Connection))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
        if (filterParameter != null) {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(filterParameter);
        }
        conn.Open();
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (rdr.Read()) {
                var c = new Customer() {
                    CustomerID = (string)rdr["CustomerID"],
                    CompanyName = (string)rdr["CompanyName"],
                    ContactName = (string)rdr["ContactName"],
                    City = (string)rdr["City"],
                    Country = (string)rdr["Country"],
                    Phone = (string)rdr["Phone"]
                };
                Customers.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Customers;
}
```

Comment: well it worked appart from the filter that I still don't understand.

Comment: I added an example. See: [SQL WHERE Clause - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp), [SQL LIKE Operator - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).